# Access the record fields in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

The problem is , I can't write **n.key >= n.left.key && n.key < n.right.key** in the **compare_children** function;

I would like to write it like in OOP node.left.right.left...

I would really like to read more about lenses but I haven't found any material on the web.

```
type avl_tree =
    Node of avl_tree_node
  | Leaf
and avl_tree_node = { 
  key : int;
  balance : int;
  left : avl_tree;
  right : avl_tree;
}

type subtree_lens = {
  get : avl_tree_node -> avl_tree;
  set : avl_tree_node -> avl_tree -> avl_tree_node
}

let lens_right = {
  get = (fun node -> node.right);
  set = fun node t -> {node with right = t}
}

let lens_left = {
  get = (fun node -> node.left);
  set = fun node t -> {node with left = t}
}

let compare_children nd =
  match nd with
  | Leaf -> true
  | Node n -> n.key >= n.left.key && n.key < n.right.key
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to look at this is that you can't write `n.left.key` because `n.left` might be a `Leaf`.

If you want to keep your type definition, you have to handle `Leaf` and `Node` as separate cases:

```
let compare_children nd =
    match nd with
    | Leaf -> true
    | Node { left = Leaf } -> (* Leaf case, fill in... *) false
    | Node { right = Leaf } -> (* Other leaf case, fill in... *) false
    | Node { left = Node ln; right = Node rn; key = k } ->
        k >= ln.key && k < rn.key
```

**Update**

An OCaml expression can look like this: `{ x with f = v }`. The type of the expression `x` must be a record type that includes a field named `f`. The expression evaluates to a record whose fields are the same as the fields of `x`, except that the `f` field has the value `v`. In fact, you can have any number of fields after `with`.

To access fields of `nd` you can make the patterns more explicit:

```
let compare_children nd =
    match nd with
    | Leaf -> true
    | Node { left = Leaf; right = Leaf } -> true
    | Node { left = Leaf; right = Node rn; key = k } -> k < rn.key
    | Node { left = Node ln; right = Leaf; key = k } -> k >= ln.key
    | Node { left = Node ln; right = Node rn; key = k } ->
        k >= ln.key && k < rn.key
```

Note that I'm just guessing at what the function is supposed to return. It's just an example of what patterns you might want to use.

Comment: Thanks @Jeffrey Scofield
One more question though

This line of code from lens_right function :
set = fun node t -> {node with right = t}
it takes a node as an argument and then creates a brand new node with its right property being set to t ?

Comment: the line : | Node { left = Leaf } tells me if nd has type an avl_tree with its left child as a Leaf, but I can't access nd here , so must I do an additional pattern matching ?